# Ambiguous Method

Tags: java, methods, paragraph, ambiguous

I have this piece of code:

```
public Paragraph paragraph() {
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(before.getLeading());
    paragraph.add(before);
    if (numbered) {
        paragraph.addSpecial(new Chunk(String.valueOf(pageN), before.getFont()));
    }
    if (after != null) {
        paragraph.addSpecial(after);
    }
    paragraph.setAlignment(alignment);
    return paragraph;
}
```

Compiler is saying that in the 2nd line I have this error:

```
reference to Paragraph is ambiguous, both method Paragraph(float) in Paragraph and method Paragraph(Chunk) in Paragraph match
```

Comment: I suspect it's something in the `Paragraph` class itself… likely there's two Constructors with similar signature. You should post this code as well.

Comment: You may need to mention/tag the programming language at least!